# mongodb document structure. Value as property name?

Tags: mongodb

comparing following 2 documents which structure is better? property "value" is usually id of different document in different collection.
Should I avoid to use the 1st structure at all?

```
{ $type : $value }
```

where type property name can have various forms. 2 example docs would be:

```
doc 1:  { "foo" : "id1"}
doc 2:  { "bar" : "id2"}
```

or 
    { "type" : $type, value: $value }
and exmaples:

```
doc 1: { type: "foo", value: "id1" }
doc 2: { type: "bar", value: "id2" }
```

In the 1st example search query has to be { "foo": {$exists:true}}
while in 2nd { type: "foo" } looks much simpler and flexible, because I can easily compare with an array {type { $in: []}}

Answer (score 0):

Your second structure

```
doc 1: { type: "foo", value: "id1" }
doc 2: { type: "bar", value: "id2" }
```

is a right approach to define a document. **It is recommended that not to use dynamic values as keys in `Mongo` document**. If you use dynamic keys, it is difficult to query on such keys. While using above given structure, you can easily query using `type` or `value` like following:

```
db.collection.find({"type":"foo"})
```

or

```
db.collection.find({"type":{"$in":["foo","abc"]}})
```